# webclient does not download the full File

Tags: c#

So, What i am having an issue with, is WebClient not Downloading the Full File. I don't know what is wrong or if there is anything wrong at all... are there other options to use to download the file besides WebClient? I have tried switching the Protocal from HTTPS to HTTP and that doesn't change anything. I have also tried the Client.Headers.Add code and that didn't change anything at all. I am at lost of what I am doing wrong! Well, here you can see my code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Kills Fiddler To Begin Process of Updates.
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Fiddler"))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
            RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
            // Disable The Proxy Created By Fiddler.
            registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 0);
            // Clears The Reserver Proxy Created By Fiddler.
            registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", "");

            // These lines implement the Interface in the beginning of program 
            // They cause the OS to refresh the settings, causing IP to realy update
            settingsReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            refreshReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            string url = "http://www.dropbox.com/s/8vqlfaxfnod8s8f/FiddlerFu.dll";
            string final = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"\Fiddler2" + @"\Scripts";
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(final);
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; U; en-US) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.10");
                client.DownloadFile(url, "FiddlerFu.dll");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked what is in the incomplete file you downloaded? If I open your link in a browser, it opens a "download" page but does not actually start the download. I'm guessing you downloaded that html page

Comment: You know, that might be it @KevinGosse. Let me rewrite the code and see!

Comment: that was it @KevinGosse, omg i can't believe I overlooked that! Thank You Soo Much! You can go ahead and marked this as Answered if you want!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a bunch of times. If you don't pick the right link, then you're actually downloading a webpage into your dll file. It's a good habit, whenever you run into this kind of issue, to try and open the dll into notepad to check what's actually in it.